Is it a bug, vulnerability or feature of C++ that I can access an array index out of bounds?
Recently, while playing around with pointers I encountered a strange string array indexing bug.
Here is a minimal example:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::string stringArr[] = {"string1","string2","string3"};
    std::string *stringArrPtr = stringArr;
    int integer = 0;
    std::cout << stringArr[3];

}

I expected that, when I ran this code, I would either get nothing, or some sort of array index error. Instead, I got interesting output that seemed to include my desktop user name and a bunch of strange characters and keywords.
I tried using some online c++ compilers and got some other strange results:

some sort of file path: /tmp/FJLCIjClAz.o,

an error message that says RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

a large amount of spaces


Why does this happen?

"bug, vulnerability or feature?" -- The C++ language does not have bugs; shortcomings are called "defects". (This is not a defect.) The C++ language does not have vulnerabilities because it does not claim to be secure; you can shoot yourself in the foot if you want (your code has the vulnerability, not the language, because you aimed at your foot). As for the last, I would be willing to call Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior a feature of the language. An often misunderstood one at that.

"expected.. nothing or some sort of array index error," -- If you want an array index error, use std::array<std::string, 3> instead of a C-style array, and access elements with the member function at() instead of the subscript operator.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, please read [ask] and take the [tour], and note carefully that this is not a discussion forum. You are expected to look for existing Q&A before asking yourself, and to be satisfied with something that answers your question even if it isn't the exact same code or situation. Please also try to give your questions a title that helps contribute to the "library" described in the [tour]; as a rule of thumb, avoid "this". Finally, as also mentioned in the tour, there's no chit-chat here.

(I have edited the question to show what questions are expected to look like. Normally we don't bother with this on questions that will be closed anyway; but I want to provide a proper example.)

While something like -fsanitize=bounds (or more generally -fsanitize=undefined) can detect out-of-bounds array access, it is difficult for instrumentation to detect issues like yours because stringArr[3] is a legal array index. You are allowed to index one-past-the-end provided you never read or write at that address.

It is a mistake for you to do so. If you want some kind of warning use std::vector<std::string> values; (or std::array) and instead of [i] use .at(i). C++ is all about don't pay for what you don't use so array bounds checking is not done for you  unless you explicitly ask for it with at(i).

The behaviour is undefined, and undefined behaviour is a feature of C++. The standard permits any outcome of undefined behaviour (whether that outcome seems logical to you or not), does not require a diagnostic, does not require runtime checks that reduce "performance".  The developer must ensure their code behaves correctly (e.g. avoid undefined behaviour by ensuring a non-existent array element is never accessed).  By doing that [which, admittedly, is not always easy] the developer is rewarded by code that is guaranteed to run correctly, without any (e.g. runtime) costs of checking.

Designers of some other languages have gone another route - they don't have undefined behaviour, but developers must accept costs of doing those checks, whether those checks are needed or not.    Difference is, marketing of those languages pretends that the checks are a necessary fact of life, rather than a design choice by the language designers.     There are advantages to those languages (particularly for novices, who get warm and fuzzies when their compiler or running program informs them of errors in their code) but they miss out on some advantages that C++ has.

C/C++ now have good tooling, you can use sanitizers and memory leak detectors like valgrind to tell you of that bug in your code, then you fix the bug and deploy a super fast app that doesn't do those unnecessary checks, unlike other languages where you are basically shipping debug builds to clients, which is not acceptable in any real application.

@paddy stringArray[3] is not a valid expression. While you can have a pointer to one-past-the-end of an array, you cannot form a reference to that hypothetical array element, because it would require to dereference the pointer, and this is not permitted.
